# Determine when an application last launched

Tags: macos, bash

I need to have a script return a date that a particular application launched (in this case Parallels, but solution should be non-specific) so that our asset management system can mark the license for re-use.

So far I've tried using the Spotlight metadata tag kMDItemLastUsedDate with

```
mdls /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_client_app \
    -name kMDItemLastUsedDate
```

but this does not always return dates that match the last time an app was used.

Any other ideas?